# How properly prepopulate DB for integration tests with Spock and Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-data-jpa, spock

I will probably provide full GitHub example of my problem but for the time being I am just asking - maybe somebody faced similar problem.

The issue is - with Spock and Spring Boot I want to run integration test and prepopulate local instance of H2 database in 'setup' method. I create several objects that can be parent to each other. So I create eg. Human1 and Human2, get their generated IDs from the sequence, then prepare REST JSON call with Human1 id as 'parentId' property and make POST to the API in order to create Human3 with Human1 as parent.

My API parses retrieved DTO, extracts 'parentId' value, and performs search using repository with method 'findOne(id)'. The problem is that at this stage the repository claims that there is no content in the database (in appropiate table).

I've tried messing around with @Transactional (it is both on my Spock specification AND on the method of mapper class), saving and flushing in setup, flushing separately both repositories and a thousands other things but nothing seems to work. So please - if anyone could at least shed a light on the problem I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You can add your answer below and accept it yourself. This way the question will be marked as "answered" and will help other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've finally stumbled upon *@BeforeTransaction* annotation that works like a charm. I put my database insert/delete logic in the separate method annotated with *@BeforeTransaction* and it is called before every single test method in a separate transaction that closes before other one associated with test method starts. And that solved the problem.